# How prove this $f(x)$ and $g_{t}(x)$ be relatively prime.

Tags: polynomials

> Let the real  coefficient polynomials
>   $$f(x)=a_{n}x^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\cdots+a_{1}x+a_{0}$$
>   $$g(x)=b_{m}x^m+b_{m-1}x^{m-1}+\cdots+b_{1}x+b_{0}$$
>   where $a_{n}b_{m}\neq 0,n\ge 1,m\ge 1$, and let
>   $$g_{t}(x)=b_{m}x^m+(b_{m-1}+t)x^{m-1}+\cdots+(b_{1}+t^{m-1})x+(b_{0}+t^m).$$
>   Show that
>
> **there exist positive $\delta$, such for any $t$ such that $0<|t|<\delta$, and such
>   $f(x)$ and $g_{t}(x)$ be relatively prime.**

I fell this result is very well, because although two polynomial are not relatively prime, we can do it to one of the polynomial tiny perturbation makes relatively prime.

But I can't prove my problem.

Thank you very much

Comment: If you can show that there are only finitely many $t$ for which they _aren't_ relatively prime, you'll practically be done (I don't know that this is true, but I feel that that's the way to go).

Comment: I think so,@Arthur,Thank you,But How prove it? Thank you

Comment: Seems obvious (haven't worked through the steps). $f(x) $ has finitely many roots that $g_t (x)$ wants to avoid.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a series of steps, which seem mostly true to me.

**Fact:** $f(x)$ has at most $n$ distinct roots.

**Claim:** There exists a map  $G: [0,1] \rightarrow (\alpha_1, \alpha_2, \ldots, \alpha_m)$ which is differentiable in each coordinate, and $ \alpha_i$ are roots of $ g_t(x)$ (with multiplicity).

Possible Proof: Use Inverse/Implicit function theorem till 2 roots meet. Then be very careful?

**Claim:** On any open interval, $\frac{dG}{d\alpha_i}$ is not identically 0.

Proof: If it does, then there is a number $ \alpha$ such that $ g_t(\alpha) = 0 $ on that open interval. But this implies that $ \sum t^i \alpha^{m-i} = 0 $ infinitely often, which is a contradiction (since there is at most $m$ values of $t$ that can satisfy the polynomial).

Hence, the result follows, where we take a small enough $t$, such that the roots of $g_t$ all avoid the roots of $f$. The final claim allows us to move off of common roots of $f$ and $g_0$ .

Comment: Nice! if you can post your full solution!+1

Comment: @math110 I'm stuck at the first claim. I don't remember enough of my analysis for a proper proof of it, but I believe that it is (very likely) true. Given that, the above is a solution.

Answer (score 2):

let $x_i$ be the roots of $f$.

$g_t$ and $f$ are not primes iif $g_t(x_i) \neq 0$ for every $x_i$.

So $g_t$ and $f$ are primes iif $t$ no in the finite set of roots of $$b_{m}x_i^m+(b_{m-1}+t)x_i^{m-1}+\cdots+(b_{1}+t^{m-1})x_i+(b_{0}+t^m)$$

Comment: You still require slightly more work, to establish that roots of $g_t$ and $f$ do not intersect for a small neighbor hood of $t$, even though $g_0$ and $f$ may not be relatively prime.

Comment: since there is a finite set of forbidden values $\{t_i\}$, I claim it exists $\delta$, such no forbidden value verifies $0<|t_i|<\delta$

Comment: Ah, I see what you are doing now. This looks good (+1). My comment was prejudiced by my approach, and doesn't apply to yours.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to check that the resultant $r(t)=Res_x(f(x), g_t(x))$, which is a polynomial in $t$, is not the zero polynomial. Any root of $r(t)$ marks a value of $t$ where both polynomials have a common factor. If $r(t)\ne 0$, the polynomials $f(x)$ and $g_t(X)$ are relatively prime.

And as in the other answers, as $r(t)$ only has a finite number of roots...